# how to deny the route to switch until has data in store with ngrx and resolve?

Tags: ngrx, angular7, ngrx-store, angular-resolver

i want to deny the user from getting to route until i have data in my store.
i tried with resolver but it still go to the route and im getting an error because im using this data in the state effect .
i searched in the web but i not see example that holds the user in resolver until the data is resolved
how can i "hold" the user until i will have the necessary data in my store?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `canActivate` or a `canLoad` guard. Todd Motto has an article on how to do this [Preloading ngrx/store with Route Guards](https://toddmotto.com/preloading-ngrx-store-route-guards)

```
@Injectable()
export class CoursesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private store: Store<CoursesState>) {}

  getFromStoreOrAPI(): Observable<any> {
    return this.store
      .select(getCoursesState)
      .do((data: any) => {
        if (!data.courses.length) {
          this.store.dispatch(new Courses.CoursesGet());
        }
      })
      .filter((data: any) => data.courses.length)
      .take(1);
  }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.getFromStoreOrAPI()
      .switchMap(() => of(true))
      .catch(() => of(false));
  }
```